# How can I send multiple objects over one socket in java?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

When I send only one object through a socket i am ok. But when i am trying to send two objects, i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source))
```

I have tried almost everything like flush() or reset() but none of them work.

```
public String SendObject(Object o) throws IOException {
    OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(outToServer);
    out.writeUnshared(o);
    InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
    return in.readUTF();
}
```

Comment: How are you sending one object? Post code.

Comment: Please edit your original post with the code you have (properly formatted). Don't put it in comments.  Also, include the exact errors that you got.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an `ObjectOutputStream` to write the `Object`(s) from the client. You should be using an [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) (not a `DataInputStream`) to read them on the server. To read two `Object`s might look something like,

```
InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inFromServer);
Object obj1 = in.readObject();
Object obj2 = in.readObject();
```

Also, on the client, I think you wanted `writeObject` (instead of [`writeUnshared`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared%28java.lang.Object%29)) like

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(outToServer);
out.writeObject(o);
```

Comment: but why does it work when i send just one object?I have tried the `WriteObject` and i had the same results

Comment: @orestiskim Did you check the [`writeUnshared`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared%28java.lang.Object%29) Javadoc?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `writeUnshared()` here: indeed, good idea if he is planning to re-send objects.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must use the same streams for the life of the socket, not new ones per send (or receive).
2. You need to decide between Object streams and Data streams. Don't mix them.
3. Don't try to mix between `writeObject()/writeUnshared()` and `readUTF().`

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers (e.g. @EJP's) are correct about the right way to send / receive objects and handle the streams, I think that the immediate problem is on the server side:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

This seems to be saying that the connection has broken before the client receives a response.  When the client side attempts to read, it sees the broken (reset) connection and throws the exception.

If (as you say) the `sendObject` method works first time, then I suspect that the server side is closing its output stream to "flush" the response ... or something like that.

Comment: so what do u suggest?

Comment: I suggest that you look at what the server side is doing.